# Перезагрузка по SNMP в Linux

Tags: linux, snmp

Есть компьютер на Linux Ubuntu.
Есть snmp-демон, прекрасно работающий на ней (из пакета snmpd).
Теперь вопрос. Можно как-то осуществить перезагрузку системы (выполнить sudo reboot, например) посредством запроса извне на эту машину?

Comment: `man snmpd.conf` на предмет директивы `exec`. Вероятно, вам потребуется написать маленький суидный хелпер. Естественно, это всё будет одной огромной дырой в безопасности.

Comment: Я новичок в linux, можете пожалуйста объяснить, что такое суидный хелпер?
Про ожидаемую уязвимость я знаю, спасибо, но ею в моем случае можно пренебречь.